# Effect of Cusco's Constitutional status as the "historical capital" of Peru

Tags: constitutional-law

Article 49 of the 1993 Constitution of Peru states that Lima is the capital. It also states that Cusco is the "historical capital".

That Cusco is the former and ancient capital would be universally known without any provision in the Constitution, and tourists would still go there to see ancient buildings and ancient monuments.

Does the Constitutional designation of Cusco as the "historical capital" have any legal or otherwise practical effects?

Comment: This might be better off on History SE. My conjecture is that the clause was added to the 1993 constitution to gain a votes among the *runa* in the 1993 referendum.